# Read &[u8] using hound WavReader

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a wavreader from [u8] using [hound](https://github.com/ruuda/hound). Haven't found a way to read from bytes, only PathBuff:

```
const file: &[u8] = include_bytes!("input.wav"); // include bytes as &[u8]
let mut reader = hound::WavReader::open(path).unwrap(); // instead of using open, is there another method?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Lucky for you [`&[u8]` implements `Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-for-%26%5Bu8%5D) so you can just use:

```rust
const file: &[u8] = include_bytes!("input.wav");
let mut reader = hound::WavReader::new(file).unwrap();
```